# How to convert powershell UTC datetime object to EST

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I have date time strings coming in, formatted like the following:

`2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z`

I need to be able to convert these to EST. Every function I have tried throws one error or another, typically being:

`"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

I have tried variations of the below:

```
$time = '2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z'
[datetime]$datetime = $time 
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
[DateTime]::ParseExact($datetime, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss', $culture)
```

I think it has something to do with how the Date Time string I am referencing has the `**T**` and then the UTC time, but can't figure out what to do about it. Maybe I should parse out the time, convert it and then reattach to the first part of the string, the date, and combine them together for the final output? Seems like way too much work and a solution which would cause potential errors in the future.

Comment: You need to change your ParseExact to the datetime format you have in your variable. `[DateTime]::ParseExact($datetime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $culture)` Note the '/' instead of the '-', That doesn't throw any errors. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to convert a Zulu time string to a `DateTime` value simply by casting it. However, the resulting value will be in local time, so you should convert it back to UTC for further calculations:

```
$timestamp = '2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z'
$datetime  = ([DateTime]$timestamp).ToUniversalTime()
```

Then you can use the [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) class to convert the UTC timestamp to the desired timezone:

```
[TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($datetime, 'Eastern Standard Time')
```

Use `[TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() | Select-Object Id, DisplayName` to get a list of the recognized timezones.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the static `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()` method of the `[System.TimeZoneInfo]` class:

```
$time = '2017-08-03T12:30:00.000Z'
$result = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date -Date $time), 'Eastern Standard Time')
```

The returned $result is a `[DateTime]`.

BTW, if you ever need to convert it back, here's how:

```
Get-Date -Date $result -Format FileDateTimeUniversal
```

Hope this helps.