# Set timezone within PowerShell Get-Date?

Tags: powershell, datetime

Is there a way to adjust the timezone within a `Get-Date` statement? I'm trying to run the following command within a PowerShell module and the date and time for the results it generates are all in PST, I'm trying to get everything into EST.

```
Start-Five9Report -FolderName [name] -ReportName [name] -EndDateTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) -StartDateTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58802973/11942268

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=net-5.0) static method. This can be done on one line but I broke it up for readability:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
  [DateTime]::Now,
  "Eastern Standard Time"
)
```

You can use [`( Get-Date )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1) in place of [`[DateTime]::Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-5.0) if you wish.

---

For the `destinationTimeZoneId` argument `"Central Standard Time"`, you can get the correct `Id` to use for each time zone by running the [`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?view=net-5.0) static method:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones()
```

and making note of the `Id` property value for the time zone you want. Note that each time zone is aware of whether it should follow Daylight Savings Time or Standard Time. You do not need to (nor will it work) provide an alternate Id for DST-enabled time zones.